# populate a clientside dropdown with a server side dropdown in aspx page using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate a clientside dropdown with a server side dropdown in aspx page with the following syntax. But this does not seem to do anything.

```
$('#' + '<%= ddClassMain.ClientID %>').find("select").clone().appendTo($('ddClass01'))
```

I have embedded this in a javascript function which gets triggered onchange() event of another clientside textbox.

I know that select is not a property of aspx dropdown. But using find("ListItem") also does not seem to work. 
Please feel free to suggest a solution or workaround.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#<%= ddClassMain.ClientID %> > option').clone().appendTo("#ddClass01");
```

With this selector expression you've select all children `option` elements of the ddClassMain `select` control. The `find('select')` method just pointless here since you don't need to copy whole dropdown to ddClass01 but only his options.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Your solution worked. Can you please explain what does
' > option' does and why did you remove .find('select')

Comment: Okay. Yes it was not making any sense to have find('select'). Just to clarify my syntax understanding, I used the following which worked
`$('#<%= ddClassMain.ClientID %>').find("option").clone().appendTo($('#ddClass01'));`
Now, I understand that just like in C, `> bar` is same as `.find('bar')`.

Again, thanks for that explanation.

Comment: @SameerShah, not exactly. The `"#id > option"` selector finds all children option tags, whereas `.find("selector")` method find all descendant elements. In this particular case both expressions are equal but generally they are processed differently. Follow this fiddle for realizing difference: http://jsfiddle.net/1stein/zLfTw/

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The `.outer > Div` just found children, while outer `(".outer").find("div")` gave the sub children too. So the point you are making is if I had a dropdown within a dropdown then the latter syntax would give me all the 'option' including the sub-dropdown which would be wrong. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the parameter in the `appendTo` has a wrong selector. Is `ddClass01` a `class`, then use `$('.ddClass01')`. If `ddClass01` is an `id`, then use `$('#ddClass01')`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing something like this which did not work:
' $('#<%= ddClassMain.ClientID %>').find("select").clone().appendTo($('#ddClass01'));'

However Mr Rozhovetskiy's solution worked. Your solution was partially right though. I was making a mistake in append to.